# 1970s or 1980s movie about where a guy uses telekinesis to stop a train

Tags: story-identification, movie, telekinesis

I remember a scene from a movie or TV show where a guy is walking on the train tracks and sees a trapped turtle.  He bends to rescue the turtle and gets his foot stuck in the switching mechanism for the tracks as a train approaches. He uses his telekinetic powers (maybe for the first time?) to stop the train and get away.  What was that show?

Answer (score 4):

This is "[The Man with the Power](https://www.shockcinemamagazine.com/manwiththepower.html)" (1977)

> At first glance, Eric Smith (Texas-bred newcomer Bob Neill) looks like
> any anonymous public school teacher. But when this klutz
> absent-mindedly gets his foot stuck in a railroad track point, some
> hitherto unknown power manages to halt an oncoming train.

Comment: YES!!!!!  thank you!!

Comment: Life is Strange!

Comment: @Greg, you can mark this as correct by clicking on the tick mark